# Using Google Speech REST APi from Node without helper module

Tags: javascript, react-native, rest, speech

I'm just getting started with a simple project in node.js.

I'm trying to use Expo for the final app but get lots of dependency conflicts in the modules so was thinking of just calling the REST API via fetch. I have a test bed that works fine using the google-supplied modules, but I always get RecognitionAduio is not supplied as an error message via REST. As you can see in the attached code, the input file, coding etc are all identical.

any views?

```
async function getAudioTranscription()  {
  const fetch = require("node-fetch");
  try {

    var filename = 'C:/Users/SteveRist/Downloads/brooklyn.flac';
    var encoding = 'FLAC';
    var sampleRateHertz = 16000;
    var languageCode = 'en-US';
    const fs = require('fs');
    const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
    const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
    console.log ('Setting REST config');
  
    const config = {
      encoding: encoding,
      sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
      languageCode: languageCode,
    };
  
    console.log ('opening ', filename);
    const audio = {
      content: fs.readFileSync(filename).toString('base64'),
    };
  
    const request = {
      config: config,
      audio: audio,
    };

    
    // Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
    // can wait for now, or get its result later.
    const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
  
    // Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
    const [response] = await operation.promise();
    const transcription = response.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n');
    console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
       
    const transcriptResponse = await fetch(
        'https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=xxx8', {
          method: 'POST',
          request: request
        }
      );

      const data = await transcriptResponse.json();
      console.log ('transcriptResponse Google returned' , data);
      const userMessage = data.results && data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript || "";
        console.log (userMessage);
 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("There was an error", error);
  }
  
}
  getAudioTranscription();
```